# Double click button on mouse

Tags: windows-10, mouse, double-click

I have a double click button on my mouse. It works fine, but I want it to click slower. I need either a free program or setting that will put a delay between the first and second clicks. I use a Windows 10 computer with the anniversary update (most recent).

Comment: Perhaps you can tell us the exact brand and model of the mouse.  In some cases, these mouse come with software from the manufacture to configure such settings as double click speed.

Comment: It is a Zelotes 5500 DPI 7 Button LED Optical Mouse (wired)

Answer (score 0):

I've pressed started button and then type mouse. Opened the mouse settings and then click advanced mouse options. There's a tab which has double click speed. It's the same since Windows 95. I guess

[image: double click mouse settings]

Comment: I've tried that, but it does not affect my double click button.